JSON_TABLE Extract lists from different nodes
I have a JSON like this, stored in a CLOB column:
{
  "code": 1,
  "required": [
    {
      "field": "R1",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "field": "R2",
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  "optional": [
    {
      "field": "O1",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "field": "O2",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "field": "O3",
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}

I want a SQL to produce a result with both required and optional values, like this:
FIELD | VALUE | REQUIRED
R1    |     1 |      YES
R2    |     2 |      YES
O1    |     1 |       NO
O2    |     2 |       NO
O3    |     3 |       NO

I can easily do it with an UNION ALL, like this:
SELECT FIELD,
       VALUE,
       'YES' AS REQUIRED
  FROM JSON_TABLE (:JSON, '$.required[*]' COLUMNS
                   FIELD PATH '$.field',
                   VALUE PATH '$.value')
UNION ALL
SELECT FIELD,
       VALUE,
       'NO' AS REQUIRED
  FROM JSON_TABLE (:JSON, '$.optional[*]' COLUMNS
                   FIELD PATH '$.field',
                   VALUE PATH '$.value')

But this JSON file is very large, so with UNION ALL it has performance issues.
How to make an SQL that produces the same results without using UNION ALL? I think this can improve performance.
I tried using the "|" operator (like JSON_TABLE (:JSON, '$.(required|optional)[*]'...) but it not works.

It's possible to use multiple NESTED PATH expressions:
with json_doc AS
(SELECT
'{
  "code": 1,
  "required": [
    {
      "field": "R1",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "field": "R2",
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  "optional": [
    {
      "field": "O1",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "field": "O2",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "field": "O3",
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}' AS json_data FROM dual
)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN jt.field_required IS NULL THEN jt.field_optional ELSE jt.field_required END AS field ,
  CASE WHEN jt.field_required IS NULL THEN jt.value_optional ELSE jt.value_required END AS value ,
  CASE WHEN jt.field_required IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS required 
from json_doc j,
     JSON_TABLE (json_data, '$' COLUMNS
                    (code PATH '$.code',
                       NESTED PATH '$.optional[*]'
                         COLUMNS (
                           field_optional PATH '$.field',
                           value_optional PATH '$.value'
                         ),                   
                       NESTED PATH '$.required[*]'
                         COLUMNS (
                           field_required PATH '$.field',
                           value_required PATH '$.value'
                         )                    
             
                    )
                )  jt;




But this JSON file is very large, so with UNION ALL it has performance issues.
Serching JSON in RDB it is always performance issues, so be careful when u use json in RDB.

So I'm not sure any other way will be much faster. Just normalize this data by extracting from json. It will be slow, but once. And then work with normalized data.
Json in RDB is lazy way to store some data structure that used as is. And there some methods to extract data but all slow and created to some edge situation like extract it to store better in future :)
You can try to use static view but i'm pretty sure it is not a good way for production.

I'm working with a third-party database, so unfortunately I'm playing the game, not making the rules.  But I'll check your suggestions. A materialized view could resolve, but I can't create a view in this database.

How big is data? may be a good way to take it from DB and make all in code? Or create some proxy DB. Need more context
